# How to debug sub-domains within VS Code for Angular projects

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

Working on a large project built using micro-services. The way clients/tenants have been designed means that to select a particular tenant you visit their particular subdomain. For EG `https://ClientA.localhost:4200` and `https://ClientB.localhost:4200`. Likewise, the port number is different per product.

Attempting to debug results in unbound breakpoints and the following errors in the debug console:

```
Could not read source map for https://clienta.localhost:4200/polyfills.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://clienta.localhost:4200/polyfills.js.map: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND clienta.localhost
Could not read source map for https://clienta.localhost:4200/runtime.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://clienta.localhost:4200/runtime.js.map: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND clienta.localhost
Could not read source map for https://clienta.localhost:4200/main.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://clienta.localhost:4200/main.js.map: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND clienta.localhost
Could not read source map for https://clienta.localhost:4200/styles.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://clienta.localhost:4200/styles.js.map: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND clienta.localhost
Could not read source map for https://clienta.localhost:4200/scripts.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://clienta.localhost:4200/scripts.js.map: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND clienta.localhost
Could not read source map for https://clienta.localhost:4200/vendor.js: Unexpected 503 response from https://clienta.localhost:4200/vendor.js.map: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND clienta.localhost
```

Launching `https://localhost:4200` will attach, but obviously the service wont function properly.

I've tried all kinds of settings for launching a browser, attaching to an existing browser, changed TypeScript settings, Angular settings, a myriad of suggested source-map settings; I'm out of ideas. What's infuriating is that I can visit (for EG) `https://clienta.localhost:4200/polyfills.js.map` and I'll receive a map as a response, so that's just salt in the wound.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One of those instances where you immediately find the answer after posting the question and bashing your head against the wall for a few days.

As I forgot to mention in the original question; in your `hosts` file, add your subdomain URLs pointing to home.

EG

```
127.0.0.1    clienta.localhost
127.0.0.1    clientb.localhost
```

The secret sauce was adding the following to `settings.json` in VS Code since I'm running over HTTPS.

```
"debug.javascript.resourceRequestOptions": {
    "https": {
        "rejectUnauthorized": false
    }
}
```

Flush your DNS cache and then you can begin debugging.

The command to flush the cache on a Macintosh is `dscacheutil -flushcache`. On Windows via CMD *and* Powershell it's `ipconfig /flushdns`